# How to post and get the merchant defined field in response page in authorize.net

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I am using SIM Authorize.net with relay response approach.

Now, when i get response back on response page then, session field value is not found.

Is there a way to post extra field on authorize.net and get the response back on response page ?

example:

My Site >>>> post additional field - "userDepartmentGUID" on transact.dll

> > > when get response then, get this field back on response page.

And i should able to access as - `Request.form["userDepartmentGUID"]'

can you please share me how i could get pass and back the field in response (as session not supporting).

I tried by posting Merchant defined value as below:

`<input type="hidden" id="m_data" name="m_data" value="data"/>`

But, in relay response URL, not able to retrieve this value.

Please guide

Thanks

Comment: I think you should ask it to support via mail support@authorize.net,, i don't know you asked before or not. But in most bank integration bank systems return the request parameters as well.